# How to read an entire sentence after it reads a specific word in C

Tags: c

I have an input, and in that input, i need the user to input their address, but it needs to contain a specific word, in this case the word "Jalan". i already tried using `strcmp` and when i input only "Jalan" it is right.

But, what i want is "Jalan blablabla....". If i input for example,
"Jalan Hasanuddin" it returns as false by `strcmp`.

To summarize i want my program to check if a specific word is in the user input and if it has that word i want the entire sentence to be read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

    char nama[20];
    char alamat[50];
    char nama_barang[30];
    int banyak_pesanan;
    int kartu_kredit;
    int limit = 1;

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t   Purchase Order Pipi Shop\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t ****************************\n");

    while(limit == 1)
{

    printf("Masukkan nama [1..20] : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", nama);
    printf("Masukkan alamat [1..50 !! mengandung \"Jalan\"] : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", alamat);

    if( strcmp(alamat, "Jalan") != 0 && strcmp(alamat, "jalan") != 0) 
{
    printf("invalid\n");
    continue;
}
        else
{
    limit -= 1;
{



}
    printf("%s", alamat);


return 0;
}
```

If i input for example: jalan hasanuddin, it would print out invalid even though it has the word 'jalan'. I need the complete sentence and i need the sentence to have the word 'jalan' in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strncmp` with the length of the name.

In your case, this would be used as:

```
if( strncmp(alamat, "Jalan", 5) != 0 && strncmp(alamat, "jalan", 5) != 0)
```

This only checks the first 5 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can learn some text search algorithms, such as the Knut-Morris-Pratt or Boyer-Moore algorithm. And in the future you will be able to solve such problems more easily.